# Sticky sidebar collapse when hitting container end

Tags: html, css

I have a structure like this

```
<page>
    <main>
        <sidebar />
        <content />
    </main>
    <footer/>
</page>
```

Let's assume the content is big enough to require scroll, i want the sidebar to be fixed with top:0, but on screens with smaller heights to shrink itself between the top:0 and end of main and be scrollable.

It is a way to achieve this with HTML and CSS only or do i have to use JS and something like intersectionObserver and give the sidebar a variable height of (100vh - what height of footer / header is visible)

[drawing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlYJx.png)

Comment: You can make sidebar scrollable by giving it a minimum height and using overflow property in css.

Comment: You can use "Sticky Sidebar" to get the sticky effect and then overflow-y: scroll; to scroll inside the sidebar

https://blixhavn.github.io/sticky-sidebar-v2/